# Define A Graph - Tree Graph With "Cycles" as Nodes

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hamiltonian-path

I am working on my thesis and I would like to have a proper definition for this type of graph:
["Tree Graph With Nodes As Cycles"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN1Kz.png)

I would like to define a graph similar to a "simple tree", but some of its nodes are replaced with some cycles. The graph should be undirected, connected and have no multiple edges between any pair of nodes. The graph is somehow similar to the picture given. My question is how to give a formal definition for this type of graph?

Edited 1: Circles should have disjoint subset of vertices. I would like to add another example for clarifying the type of graph that I would like to define: 
[Another Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYwpc.png)

Comment: The graph in the image is just ... a graph. However what you might be after is a 'block-cut tree'. If each cycle (or block, more generally) in your graph is contracted to a vertex, then you have a tree

Comment: @gilleain I just looked up what you suggested, and I think I should add more constraints on the graph I want to define. Could you take a look on my "Edited 1" part? I just added another example. Basically the cycles should have no common vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A snappy definition of your object is "a connected graph in which every vertex is part of at most one cycle".

If cycles could touch and share up to one vertex, this would be a [cactus graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph). (Here, the condition is that every *edge* is part of at most one cycle.) Your graphs are a subclass of these, but with no existing terminology.

If you want a term, you might have to make something up. A cactus graph in which each vertex is part of at most two cycles is a *Christmas cactus*, according to the Wikipedia link above. You're looking for a condition that's one stricter than this condition, so perhaps it should be a *Christmas Eve cactus*?

Also quoting Wikipedia:

> In topological graph theory, the graphs whose cellular embeddings are all planar are exactly the subfamily of the cactus graphs with the additional property that each vertex belongs to at most one cycle. These graphs have two forbidden minors, the diamond graph and the five-vertex friendship graph.

This doesn't name your family of graphs, but links to a paper where they're discussed further: [https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(72)90040-8](https://doi.org/10.1016%2F0095-8956%2872%2990040-8).

Comment: Your suggested "snappy definition" is actually what I need. If I am to define a graph class such that each vertex of any graph that belongs to this class is a part of at most one cycle, will that be sufficient enough?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to your definition. The graph consists of a bunch of (necessarily) vertex-disjoint cycles, which are joined by paths to make it connected, and the paths can't create any further cycles so they have the structure of a tree.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Call a graph $G$ an *almost-tree* iff
(1) $V(G) = U_1+U_2+\ldots +U_m +W$ where the $U_i$s are disjoint sets of vertices of cardinality at least 3

(2) $G[U_i]$ is a cycle on $|U_i|$ vertices

(3) the resulting graph $f(G)$ formed by collapsing each $U_i$ to a single vertex $v_i$ and where there is an edge $v_iv_j$ [respectively, $v_iw$; $w \in W$] iff there is an edge in $G$ between a vertex in $U_i$ and $U_j$ [respectively, iff there is an edge in $G$ between a vertex in $U_i$ and $w$], is a tree.

(4) For all $i,j$ there is at most one edge between the vertices in $U_i$ and the vertices $U_j$, and for each $i$ and $w \in W$ there is at most one edge between the vertices in $U_i$ and $w$.

Note that given an almost-tree $G$, that the tree $f(G)$ is well-defined and unique. Call $\{U_1,\ldots, U_m, W\}$ the *cycle-partitioning* of the vertices of the almost-tree $G$. Note that this cycle-partitioning is well-defined and unique as well.

This is how I would do it.

Comment: Could you clarify (3)? Does it also cover the case that there could be a tree between two cycles? I'm sorry if I sound not so clear about what I mean, here is an example: 
https://ibb.co/SvGMrZ9

Comment: @Jack see my editted answer. The change I made in the definition above does allow there to be a tree between two cycles.

Comment: Thank you. This is quite a good formal definition!