# Induction Proof On "Tree with Nodes as Cycles" Graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hamiltonian-path, path-connected

So I have one question about defining the type of graph I was working on: [Define A Graph - Tree Graph With "Cycles" as Nodes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317144/define-a-graph-tree-graph-with-cycles-as-nodes)

A short summary for the graph I would like to define as G=(V,E):

> **Definition 1:** *A tree with nodes as cycles* is connected, loop-less graph (no multiple edges) in which every vertex is part of at most one cycle.

This means the cycles have disjoint sets of vertices in the graph.
Here I also want to have another definition of an *cycle-connected* vertex:

> **Definition 2:** A *cycle-connected vertex v* is a vertex that has degree larger than 2 and belongs to a particular cycle *C*. Furthermore, there must exist a unique path from *v* to another cycle in G such that the path does not contain any vertex of the cycle *v* belongs to.

For the question, I would like to prove this theorem by induction proof:

> Given a graph G=(V,E) described above with k cycles in the graph where k is larger than 1. There must be at least two cycles that have only **one** cycle-connected vertex.

Thoughts: If I am correct, It seems like we can prefer to these cycles as a "cycle-leaf" in a tree. So we can say that there exists at least two "cycle-leaves" the the type of graph we defined for any *k* larger than 1.

**Proofs**

**1. Base case:** If *k=2*, then we have only two cycles connected to each other. By **definition 2**, we have that each cycle has *one cycle connected vertex*. Thus, the base case holds.

**2. I assume that for k=n**, we have at least two cycles that have only *one cycle connected vertex*. I prefer these two cycles as "cycle-leaves".

**3. I assume now for k=n+1**, we have two ways to add one more cycle:

_ Connecting the new cycle to one of the cycle-leaves, then the newly added cycle will become a leaf. Thus we still have at least two cycle-leaves.

_ Connecting to another cycle which is not the two cycle-leaves, then we can still guarantee to have two cycle-leaves that are left untouched. We conclude that the case *k=n+1* also holds. So the theorem is proved.

Do you think this is sufficient or am I missing something?

Comment: My graph theory professor would have gone on a rant at the thought of a a graph with n+1 cycles being generated by an n cycle graph with "one more added".  He would insiste that you let G be a graph with n+1 cycles and then you'd have to figure out how to take one away to be able to use the induction hypothesis.  This now feels like a reasonable position to me, although that may be the trauma speaking.  ^_^

Comment: I think you should structure it like the analogous proof that a tree has at least two leaves -- consider a maximal path and reason that the endpoints are isolated, or note that if there are no cycle-leaves then there must be a larger cycle that connects your cycle-connected vertices.