# what is the good way to count all the cycles in this undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

For [this undirected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K16yB.gif), what is the best way to count all the cycles? I started with node A, then B, C, D. It took me lots of time, and quite confusing. Here is what I got: ABDA, ABCA, ABCDA, ACDA, ACDBA, BCDB, CBDAC, not quite sure if I got all of them, but the process was quite painful, I wonder if there is a better way to count all the cycles in undirected graph?

Comment: This is the complete graph $K_4$, so both three- and four-cycles with vertices in any order are possible.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so 
1, how many cycles in total?
2, how did you get the total number?
Thanks.

Comment: I'll get you started.  There are $4$ triangles, and you can traverse each triangle in either of $2$ directions, so there are $8$ possible $3$-cycles.  Can you figure out how many $4$-cycles there are?

Comment: good points, for 4-cycles, looks like there are 3(ABCDA, ADBCA, ACDBS)*2=4. what is the general principle(if it does not have triangles, ) to count the cycles in undirected graph?  Any good articles/resources you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did get all the cycles. A systematic method for complete graphs is to note that cycles of $K_n$ can have any length from $3$ to $n$.
The number of cycles of length $\ell$ is the number of ways of choosing $\ell$ vertices times the number of ways of ordering the vertices (up to cyclic permutation) divided by $2$. (I am assuming that a "cycle" is a subgraph that is a cycle graph, which implies that reversing the order of visitation doesn't give a new cycle.) Putting this together gives
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\ell=3}^n\binom{n}{\ell}(\ell-1)!
$$
for the number of cycles. For more information, you can look at the [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A002807) and the references given there.

The general problem seems hard, for the reasons described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3322338/3736). The [MathWorld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) appears to contain a lot of useful information.